# Evaluating a contour integral using Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Suppose $f(z)$ is an entire function such that $|\overline{f(z)} - 3 - 4i|\le 5$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(0) = 3$. Evaluate $$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z}dz$$

I think the answer is $2\pi if(0) = 6\pi i$ according to Cauchy integral formula but if this would be true then the given inequality is useless. So what's the problem of my answer?

Comment: Yes, the given inequality is useless.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that $f$ is necessarily *constant.*

Comment: @MartinR That's right but the value of integral is necessarily $2\pi i f(0)$ .

Comment: Sure. I do not know what the intention of that problem is. The given condition would allow to compute the integral without Cauchy's integral formula if you know Liouville's theorem.